# Angular style binding onMouseMove

Tags: angular

I'm new to ng7 and I'm trying to create component which will follow mouse. So what I need to do is bind style of div. My html is:

```
<div class="follower" [ngStyle]="{'left': leftPos, 'top': topPos}"></div>
```

and js:

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-follower',
  templateUrl: './follower.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./follower.component.scss']
})
export class FollowerComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])

  topPos: string;
  leftPos: string;

  onMouseMove(e) {
      this.topPos = e.clientY + 'px';
      this.leftPos = e.clientX + 'px';
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

for some reason it doesn't work correctly printing some weird errors in console.

> ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_3(...).topPos is not a function

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) decorator must be followed by the event handler method. To prevent the error, move the declarations of `topPos` and `leftPos`, so that `onMouseMove` immediately follows the decorator:

```
topPos: string;
leftPos: string;

@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
onMouseMove(e) {
  this.topPos = e.clientY + 'px';
  this.leftPos = e.clientX + 'px';
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxgpus?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffollower.component.ts) for a demo.